# Create DotNetNuke Module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-8

I am a mid-level c#/.Net developer. I was asked to create a Dotnetnuke module. In your opinion, what is the best way to learn how to create modules? Is there a site/video/tutorial that is more beneficial than most? I will be using Dotnetnuke 8.**.

**UPDATE**
Since opinion based questions are not allowed then please just list places to learn how to create dotnetnuke modules.

Comment: this is a very general, what-do-you-prefer question which I believe is usually downvoted because it doesn't adhere to stack overflow policy

Comment: DNNHero.com has module development training videos for DNN 7 and 8

Answer (score 1):

My opinion may be slightly biased....

http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/DNN8-Tutorials

Use my free Visual Studio project templates  http://cjh.am/dnntemplates

Setup your local development environment as instructed in the videos (using http://dnndev.me/)

Comment: ha, nice chris.  I'll put my two cents in and say these templates are definitely the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I have an account at http://www.dnncreative.com/ that has helped me a lot!!

Answer (score -1):

We believe that developing in DNN has a few requirements you must adhere to, to ensure you're ready for the future. These requirements include:

1. avoid any kind of webforms-specific mechanism, as they are end of life and have been for quite a while now
2. use Razor for server side templating and JS for most logic - this ensure you're on current technologies and ready for .net core
3. use webapi for actions / data / state change

You can do this manually with a lot of plumbing using MVC modules, or do it 10x faster using 2sxc (check 2sxc.org).

Love from Switzerland,
Daniel